# Printing to a txt or csv file in native c++ code in Android app development

Tags: android, c++, csv, android-ndk

I did search for printing to a text or csv file in native part. People discussed using `AAssetManager_open & AAsset_read` to asset folder. But my text file is just for debugging purpose so that I consider I don't need to use those. I just implemented my code as follow

```
     LOGD("file start");
    std::ofstream ofs("/data/data/com.prg.astralinkpeoplecount/image.csv", ios::out | ios::app);
    LOGD("file created");
    // for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i) {
        // for each column
        const unsigned char* img_ptr = (unsigned char*) img.data + img.step * i;
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j)
            ofs << *(img_ptr+j) << ',';
        ofs << "\n";
    }
    ofs.close();
```

The code run. But I can't find csv file in any folder.
What could be missing?
Thanks

Comment: You probably have a secured device where you cannot readily access the app's private folder.  Put your debug output on the external storage instead, but don't guess the path, call the java api and pass the path into your native code (your app vs. the adb shell or ddms explorer will actually have to use different paths to reach the same file).

Comment: I printed to SDCARD directly and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I implemented as printing to SDCARD and it works. My code is as follow.

```
int print(Mat &img) {

    LOGD("file start");
    std::ofstream ofs("/sdcard/mysdfile.csv", ios::out | ios::app);
    LOGD("file created");
    if(ofs!=NULL)
    {
        // for each row
        for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i) {
            // for each column
            const unsigned char* img_ptr = (unsigned char*) img.data + img.step * i;
            for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j)
                 ofs << *(img_ptr+j) << ',';
             ofs << "\n";
         }
         ofs.close();
         LOGD("file closed");
    }
//
    LOGD("file printed");
    return 0;
}
```